# Accessing nested object literal object undefined?

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, object-literal

So I'm very new at object literal pattern but really excited about this pattern and the organization it provides.

What I'm trying to do is update the phone number form field on-the-fly to format as users type (###-###-####).  However, I want to make the formatting functionality a sort of reusable utility so I can assign it accordingly to other inputs without rewriting the function's functionality every time...all the while trying to use the Object Literal pattern

I have a fiddle setup http://jsfiddle.net/JF3Vh/3/

Here's what I have thus far...Caution learning in progress...

**HTML**

```
<div id="contactPage">
  <form>

    <label id="lblPhone" for="txtPhone">Your Phone Number:</label>
    <input id="txtPhone" name="phone" type="tel"/>                      

  </form>
</div>
```

**JavaScript using jQuery**

```
var appMobile = {

    utilities: {

        formatPhone : function(){
            alert( "formatPhone is running" );
            $( this ).val().replace(/(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{4})/, "$1-$2-$3");
        }

    },
    page: {
    home : {function()
       //Some Page specific functions here
    },
    contactForm: function () {
            $( '#txtPhone' ).onchange(function() {
                $(this).appMobile.utilities.formatPhone();
            });
        },
    products : {function()
       //Some Page specific functions here
    },


    }


};


$( document ).ready( function () {

    /*--initialize Scheduling page function--*/
    if ( $( '#contactPage' ) ) { appMobile.page.contactForm(); }

} );
```

Set me straight and thanks! :)

WizzyBoom

Comment: Syntax error: `home : {function() {}`

Comment: @Šime Vidas Fixed. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do believe this is what you were going for:

```
var appMobile = {
    utilities: {
        formatPhone: function(){
            alert( "formatPhone is running" );
            $( this ).val().replace(/(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{4})/, "$1-$2-$3");
        }
    },
    page: {
        home: function() {
           //Some Page specific functions here
        },
        contactForm: function () {
            $('#txtPhone').on('change', appMobile.utilities.formatPhone);
        },
        products: function() {}
           //Some Page specific functions here
        }
    }
};

$(function () {
    if ($('#contactPage').length) { 
        appMobile.page.contactForm(); 
    }
});
```

Also, you may be interested in [this](http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/) masked edit plugin.

Comment: @Joshiah, thank you for your response.  One question then, I noticed that you took the IF statement checking to see what page is loaded (contactPage in this case) and just put it in a straight function.  Two questions, 1) Why?, don't we need to sort of "kick off" running the functions once the document is ready to go, thus the '$(document).ready();'? 2) How? How come this approach works? It doesn't seem like anything is calling the '$(function () { _IF STATEMENT_ });' Won't it just get parsed in the DOM and just sit there "on ice" until something calls it?

Comment: See [here](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) the `$(function(){});` is just shorthand for `$(document).ready(function(){});`. Internally jQuery just type-checks the first argument for a function vs a selector, element, etc.